python pipes deprecated, how to fix
I wrote some years ago an iTunes-replacing program in Python, and recently I started to get a warning DeprecationWarning: 'pipes' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13.
This is due to the fact that I play my mp3's by mpg123 using the pipes library, e.g. snippets like this scattered here and there:
t = pipes.Template()        
t.append("echo jump +10s", '--')
f = t.open(mpgpipe, 'w')
f.close()    

What can I do to replace it?

I'm not familiar with the pipes library, but I think the currently preferred method is using the subprocess module. This is also recommended in the deprecation info for the pipes library.

I'll assume mpgpipe is the name of a named pipe (e.g. the name of something you've passed to mpg123 --fifo ...).
In that case, just
with open(mpgpipe, "w") as f:
    f.write("jump +10s\n")


I wasnt able to make it work. I did mpgpipe = "/tmp/mpg123remote.cmd"; os.mkfifo(mpgpipe); with open(mpgpipe, "w") as f: f.write("jump +10s\n") but it doesnt work - nothing more I can say: no error, simply mpg123 doesnt react...
